# Grub error installing Xubuntu 23.04

Tags: grub2

at the end of Xubuntu 23.04 clean installation I get a Grub fatal error.
How can I resolve?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS install? What brand/model system? All systems since 2012 are UEFI. What specific error? Missing ESP - efi system partition for UEFI or missing bios_grub if gpt but old (very old) BIOS install?